# Application_Start ()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know before calling this event ( Application Start) . database has been created?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What database are you talking about? And why do you need to know that **before** your app starts?

Comment: sql server and i want to add some data .

Comment: and what hinders you in doing so within the handler?

Comment: if this method run before database .this will give error. and this method just fire once time.

Comment: Sounds fishy. Database connections should be taken from a managed pool, which should be available by the time you need to write to the db. What exactly is it that you are trying to write? Seeding Data?

Comment: instead of trying to workaround an error you should try to fix it in the first place. However we cannot help you if you don't provide what error you actually get and what exactly you are trying to do with whatever database. What is the data and where is it written?

Comment: @Flidor i want to add data to db table like roles ( admin , user)....yes seeding data.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain i dont really get any error its just Hypothesis ( if there is not any db this data whitch i want to add will give me error.) now i want to know db has been created before this event run?

Comment: Database being created and seeding the database with data are two different things. If you want your app to be responsible for seeding it with data, there's nothing stopping you from adding logic to do that as the first thing that runs in the Application_Start method.